# Can adults learn grammar like 5 or 6 year old kids?

Tags: learning-methods

As the title said. Learning a language is complicated, but children can easily pick up any languages around them. Can adults learn grammar like toddlers? and How?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. It looks like your question is a bit too broad. For example, you should specify whether this is about learning foreign languages. In addition, language learning is a very broad subject, so instead of saying, "As the title said", you should specify which aspect of learning "like 5 or 6 year old kids" you are interested in, instead of adding a second question ("Also, I would like to know how to learn grammar unconsciously.") Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Edited...........

Comment: Child language acquisition is already covered in [What are the steps to native language acquisition for children?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3038/800). And your question is still very broad since it implicitly covers all aspects of language learning. Questions that require book-length answers are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: I believe the first version of your question asked whether adults can learn grammar in a way similar to 5-6-year-old children. If you narrow down your question like this, it can get re-opened.

Comment: edited...............